# Best way to tile an image in a UIScrollView, memory and performance

Tags: image, uiscrollview, xamarin.ios, uiimage, tile

I'm trying to find the BEST way (performance and memory usage both Real and Virtual memory) to tile an image inside a `UIScrollView`.  What this basically comes down to is -> some tiling methods give great scrolling performance(ie: no lag when scrolling/zooming) but use a lot of memory/virtual memory, and other methods give better memory usage with worse performance.

Here are the things I've tried so far:

- Using `UIGraphics` Context with the `UImage` `DrawAsPatternInRect` method to tile the image for me.  This produces one image with little real Memory usage, but bloats virtual memory when producing a large image.  The scrolling performance is good
- Using an array of `UIImageView`'s that are displaying the same `UIImage`.  I'm manually tiling the `UIImageView`'s myself.  This works well for memory usage, but the scrolling/zooming performance suffers when you have too many `UIImageView`'s (and I'll have a lot for what I'm doing).  So to prevent the performance suffering I'll have to implement some optimization in order to make the performance bearable.

Any better methods that would have good scrolling performance and NOT bloat virtual/real memory?

Thanks

Comment: From this and your previous question, it looks like you're developping some kind of game. Instead of reinveinting the wheel and developping a game on top of `UIView`s, why not use a game development plaftorm, like `cocos2d`, `monogame`, `SpriteKit` ? You'll find built-in functions or tutorials on how to achieve your goals with most of those platforms.

Comment: Thanks for the advice.  This current game is mostly a learning thing for me, though it is a lot like re-inventing the wheel.  I do plan on developing my next game with a game engine, and I have some good options in mind.